# (windows cmd) how to unset multiple environment variable in one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I can set http_proxy and https_proxy within one line:
[image]
But when I try to unset them with `set=`, the `https_proxy` is gone, but I can still see `http_proxy`.
[image]
How can I delete `http_proxy` too?

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the error you've identified, there is a method of doing this for variables that share a prefix using a For loop:

```bat
(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims==" %%G in ('Set http')Do Set "%%G=") 2> nul
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the extended `set-syntax`.

```
set "var="
```

The positions of the quotes are important here, the first quote is in front of the variable name, the last quote terminates the expression, remaining characters or spaces are ignored.

```
set "http_proxy=" & set "https_proxy="
```

Even this works

```
set "http_proxy=" hello & set "https_proxy=" world, will be ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the space before the second `set` causes the problem.

```
set http_proxy=& set https_proxy=
```